# Python += operator behaves differently when using function return value

Tags: python

I am assigning a variable `self.totalProb` to the return value of the function `knightHelper()` using the `+=` operator. Whenever the `knightHelper()` function returns a 0 value, the value of `self.totalProb` is reset to 0; it should remain the same, because it should just add 0 to the total.

I have written a workaround to this problem by assigning the return value of `knightHelper()` to an intermediate value, and then updating `self.totalProb` using the `+=` operator (it works this way).

I can't figure out why it doesn't work when I don't use an intermediate variable.

```py
class Solution:        

    def knightHelper(self, numberMoves, r, c, K, N, probability):
        possibleMoves = [
            (2,1), (2,-1), (-2,1), (-2,-1),
            (1,2), (-1,2), (1,-2), (-1,-2),
        ]

        if ( numberMoves > K ):
            return probability

        for move in possibleMoves:
            result = ( r + move[0], c + move[1] )

            if ( (result[0] >= 0 and result[0] < N) and (result[1] >= 0 and result[1] < N) ):
                # If the move is on the board, call the function recursively & increment the goodMoves variable

                if ( probability == 0 ): newProb = 1/8
                else: newProb = ( probability * (1/8) )

                # *********** ISSUE IS HERE: *********** 
                # The following 2 lines are resetting the sum whenever the helper function returns 0
                self.totalProb += self.knightHelper(numberMoves+1, result[0], result[1], K, N, newProb)
                print(self.totalProb)

                """ # If it's done this way, with an intermediate variable, it works...

                probabilityToAdd = self.knightHelper(numberMoves+1, result[0], result[1], K, N, newProb)
                self.totalProb += probabilityToAdd
                print(self.totalProb) """

        return 0


    def knightProbability(self, N: int, K: int, r: int, c: int) -> float:

        if ( K == 0 ): return 1
        if ( N < 3 ): return 0

        self.totalProb = 0

        self.knightHelper(1, r, c, K, N, 0)

        return self.totalProb

S = Solution()
print( S.knightProbability(3,2,0,0) )
```

Expected result should print:

```
0.015625
0.03125
0.03125
0.046875
0.0625
0.0625
0.0625
```

Actually prints:

```
0.015625
0.03125
0
0.015625
0.03125
0
0
```

Comment: Is the function really supposed to be recursive? Can you explain the logic?

Comment: `def knightProbability(self, N: int, K: int, r: int, c: int) -> float:` totally ignores the return value of `knightHelper`

Comment: @clemens - knightHelper does not always return 0. Earlier in the function it can return the value of the 'probability' variable. I agree with you that the provided code is confusing, but at the moment I cannot see why the two implementations should provide different results.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you have a recursive exploration of your possible moves but you are writing results into only a single instance variable `self.totalProb`. Here is your "bad" implementation line :

```
self.totalProb += self.knightHelper(numberMoves+1, result[0], result[1], K, N, newProb)
```

This line is equivalent to the (equally "bad") line :

```
self.totalProb = self.totalProb + self.knightHelper(numberMoves+1, result[0], result[1], K, N, newProb)
```

However this alterative is "good" (ie works) :

```
self.totalProb = self.knightHelper(numberMoves+1, result[0], result[1], K, N, newProb) + self.totalProb
```

That's because executing `self.knightHelper` overwrites the value of `self.totalProb`.

By modifying `self.totalProb`, executing `self.knightHelper` changes the state of the system. You should make `self.knightHelper` to be stateless (or at least to manage the state internally on the system stack as part of the recursion).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this statement:
"`self.knightHelper` overwrites the value of `self.totalProb`"
I don't see how `self.totalProb` is overwritten, I thought it was just updated